# Angular export csv multiple value field in one field

Tags: angular, csv

As you can see on the second field of the CSV the values are separated and surrounded with hooks and quotation marks. this is my code to export:

```
`
export() {
    let teams = this.dataSource.filteredData.map(
        ({team_name,mentor,candidates
         }) =>
            ({"TeamName":team_name,
              "Mentors":mentor.map(m=>({'FirstName' : m.firstName,'LastName':m.lastName})),
              "Candidates":candidates.map(({firstName,lastName})=>(firstName && lastName)).join('-')}))
    this.dataService.exportCSV(teams,"Teams")
  }`
```

And this is the result:[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi3RF.png)

How can I have something like this when I export(with commas only): [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXEzZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things which you should correct

1. .join('-') will return you strings are divided to '-', I guess you need ','
2. firstName && lastName will return you only the first value, it means you get the only firstName. So use concat instead. firstName + ' ' + lastName
3. add .join(',') to Mentors in order to return string instaed of an array
4. m=>({'FirstName' : m.firstName,'LastName':m.lastName}) will return you an object, but you need the string. So change it to (m=>(m.firstName + ' ' + m.lastName))

Finally, you code will be like below

```
let teams = this.dataSource.filteredData.map(
            ({team_name,mentor,candidates}) =>
                ({"TeamName":team_name,
                  "Mentors":mentor.map((m)=>(m.firstName + ' ' + m.lastName)). join (','),
                  "Candidates":candidates.map(({firstName,lastName})=>(firstName + ' ' + lastName)).join(',')}))
```